# List of nodes that have no taxonomy terms

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, 6

I'm maintaining a D6 project, where the customer wants to see a list of nodes where no taxonomy terms were added.

I want to solve this with views. I already tried some Filter settings for that, but nothing worked so far.

I would know the solution in D7 with Views 3 but in this case I can't get rid of this problem.

Comment: Tell your customer Drupal 6 is no longer supported. [On February 24th 2016, Drupal 6 will reach end of life and no longer be supported](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-6-eol) and that it is in his best interest to upgrade to 7 or possibly 8 depending if all the modules needed have been ported to 8.

Comment: we're allready talked to them and gave them the advice to do that, but it's all about the money ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
1. create a node view
2. in 'Fields', add 'Node: nid'
3. in 'Relationships', add 'Taxonomy: Node'
4. in 'Filters', add 'Taxonomy: Vocabulary', in next step, choose 'Is empty (NULL)' as the operator.
5. test some of the nids given in the preview to see if they are the ones you are looking for, you might need to tweak a little the usage of relationship.
Step #3 is here to give you extra operators to choose from.

---

**update**

Okay the above assumes the content type only has one term field, so nevermind...
Now that I understand the issue better, I think you will probably need [views_or](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_or) module. Also we don't need 'relationship' anymore.

On my test Views, I use filter 'taxonomy:term(term id)' for each vocabulary, chain them together via Views_or. Set them to dropdown with hierarchy. Then highlight all terms in the vocab and check 'is none of' for the operator on the left. It's a very ugly query but that's the only way I got it to work...You'd better cache it for a better performance. I attached some [screenshots](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tdtmk8pxs15i7wb/AAAHkKFxmMCTEoavSQBFNZO5a?dl=0) hope to clarify the config part.

Comment: Thx for your answer! Unfortunately it doesn't work. 
maybe there is a problem because, in the node there is more than 1 vocabulary used?

Comment: @themca hrm what kind of nodes does Views give you after you use the 'Is empty' filter? Still nodes with taxonomy terms? Would like to see the query if possible.

Comment: `SELECT node.nid AS nid, node_term_node.nid AS node_term_node_nid, node.title AS node_title, node.type AS node_type, node.uid AS node_uid, node_revisions.format AS node_revisions_format, node.created AS node_created FROM node node  LEFT JOIN term_node term_node ON node.vid = term_node.vid LEFT JOIN node node_term_node ON term_node.vid = node_term_node.vid LEFT JOIN term_data term_data ON term_node.tid = term_data.tid LEFT JOIN node_revisions node_revisions ON node.vid = node_revisions.vid WHERE (node.type in ('redaktionsrezept', 'rezept')) AND (term_data.vid IS NULL)`

Comment: There are no nodes, but there should be at least one (removed taxonomy terms manually)

Comment: Query should be correct, I can't think of any problems... I suppose you get the same outcome when you don't include 'content type' in the filter? thanks.

Comment: Same situation, all other content types are shown but not even one of the other content types where no taxonomy terms are used.

Hmm maybe there is a communication problem between us, i tried to scetch up the problem on a paper: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sclmsc8e7hn1yv8/Datei%2010.06.16%2C%2007%2023%2054.jpeg?dl=0

Comment: Vocabulary 1 and Vocabulary 2 are fields of the specific content type where you can add terms.

Comment: okay so if the node doesn't have value in either (or both) of these two term fields, the node should be output by the Views, correct?

Comment: yes that's correct